Indefinite article usage
Even with uncountable nouns, for specific instances/types, we have nouns preceded by indefinite articles as in the following examples.

It is cold outside! I could do with a hot tea!
The old diesel engines cause a deadly pollution in this city.
She always had a deep distrust of strangers.

Considering the above examples, Why does the following only take the definite article? Or Can it take the article 'a?'

I advise you against the habitual drinking of alcohol.


What leads you to believe that only the definite article is possible? And are you asking about the particular gerund drinking or about gerunds in general?

"the habitual drinking" is seen as one thing, it's not an instance of a larger set of things. I think this is just the idiomatic way that "habitual" is used. (Although some -ing forms are closer to becoming fully-fledged nouns than others, and "drinking" is further away than many.)

@StuartF That doesn't make sense. What about "occasional drinking?" or "frequent drinking?" Altogether I have listed 3 types of drinking and each one could be an instance.

(1) Here, 'a hot tea'  is a count usage, like 'a pint' / 'a couple of pints' / 'six coffees to go'. Pollution is imo indeterminate here, probably non-count (Wiktionary licenses both count and non-count usages). 'Distrust' is best seen as non-count here, though again Wiktionary licenses both count and non-count usages. // Very few relevant  hits in a Google search for "a habitual drinking" demonstrate that it's far from idiomatic (though 'a habitual drinking of tea / water' both occur, and sound better). The use of an indefinite article with a non–count-noun usage is idiosyncratic, and is ...

far from being a totally productive feature.

far from being a totally productive feature. // See the analysis and references at a blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight? // [including]  Formal / literary style:
• The director spoke at the meeting today with an enormous enthusiasm. /
• She smiled at us with an unusual friendliness.  //
Standard / everyday style:  •  The director spoke at the meeting today with enormous enthusiasm. / • She smiled at us with an unusual friendliness.

It looks like indefinite articles can occur before a Gerund. e.g., A singing in a sweet voice soothes the mind. "An auditing of the accounts will reveal the correct position." "A good spanking used to be recommended for misbehaving children."

There's no reason the grammar wouldn't allow 'a habitual drinking of alcohol' as we have examples like

These are not discrete problems that can be solved one at a time: they
are interconnected catastrophes linked to decades of underinvestment
in working families, and a habitual misunderstanding of the role
that childcare and early childhood education play in the nation’s
economic prosperity. (Guardian)

but it does not conform to idiom, the idiomatic expression being 'a habit of drinking alcohol' for which there are plenty of high quality examples.

2% of the respondents aged between 15 and 17 indicated that they had
a habit of drinking alcohol (news.gov.hk)

If we wanted to reword this to include the phrase in question, the result would be awkward at best

2% of the respondents aged between 15 and 17 indicated that their lives included a habitual drinking of alcohol

In fact, most instances of 'a habitual -ing of ...' can be reworded in a more idiomatic way, which accounts for this construction's lack of prevalence. For example

In the words of the Bar Association of Sri Lanka in a letter which is
the most recent in what has become a habitual expressing of' deep
concern',' there was a perception among judicial officers that there
was an effort to impress upon them to give orders.' (The Sunday Times, Sri Lanka)

Would probably be more idiomatic as a habit of expressing.

Thanks! I have upvoted your answer.
